# GWT framework application working in IE11, but not working in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, gwt

I'm working on a gwt framework application, which connects to a server and retrieves data.
Everything is working fine in IE11.
In chrome I don't even get the validation error message even if i'm not filling the required fields.
In tomcat log i could see the following errors:

```
"GET /migrationService/MpMigration.html HTTP/1.1" 200 1126

"GET /migrationService/com.XXXXX.XXXXXX.migration.MpMigration.nocache.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -

"GET /migrationService/AF5CE69AE2DE811DAD02613D78BEF2F3.cache.html HTTP/1.1" 200 107045

"GET /migrationService/XXXX_logo_NoTag_RGB_150p.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 2638

"GET /migrationService/Connecting.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 58789

"GET /migrationService/wizard.css HTTP/1.1" 200 3638

"POST /migrationService/migrateService HTTP/1.1" 500 57

"POST /migrationService/migrateService HTTP/1.1" 500 57
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

500 means something is going wrong in the service.
Check your service for a stacktrace.